# Invalidating argument by being unable to distinguish the basic terms

Tags: logic, fallacies

What is the exact name of the logical fallacy, where one invalidates the arguments by claiming that the terms on which the argument is built are indistinguishable, e.g.:

> You have stated that politics often influences economics. This is what is meaningless, because economics is politics.

I suppose, if one were to enter a discussion of terminology, this would boil down to some kind of [false equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence). As is, it seems using unconventional definition of the terms, so it is somehow similar to [Syntactic ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity) (but we are obviously not dealing with syntax here.) Alternatively, it could be a case of [ignoratio elenchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrelevant_conclusion) or [overwhelming exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overwhelming_exception).

**Rermark:**
The term *economics* (the research discipline) here is used here as meaning *economy* (the phenomenon.)

**Related questions:**
[What is the name of the fallacy: 'we cannot clearly distinguish one thing from another'?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/15379/61899)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139980/discussion-on-question-by-roger-vadim-invalidating-argument-by-being-unable-to-d).

Answer (score 1):

The form of the argument in your question is this:

'You have said that A causes B, but A cannot cause B, because A=B'

So, the interlocutor is being accused of conflating two concepts by thinking that one causes ("influences", etc.) the other.

This is not a fallacy with a name. However, a particular application of this 'fallacy' has a long and storied history in the philosophy of mind. Specifically, Cartesians about the mind maintain that the mind and body are distinct (caveat: Descartes himself could be cagey about exactly what the distinction was), while critics have argued that the arguments typically deployed for this claim are flawed in one of a variety of ways.

Arnauld makes such an argument in the Fourth Objections to Descartes's Meditations. Summary here: [https://iep.utm.edu/antoine-arnauld/#:~:text=Arnauld%20argues%20that%20given%20Descartes,does%20not%20reflect%20Pythagoras'%20Theorem](https://iep.utm.edu/antoine-arnauld/#:%7E:text=Arnauld%20argues%20that%20given%20Descartes,does%20not%20reflect%20Pythagoras%27%20Theorem).

Gilbert Ryle refers to a version of the kind of conflation mentioned here as a "category mistake" in "The Concept of Mind".

See the section on Leibniz's Law Arguments here: https://iep.utm.edu/dualism-and-mind/

Broadly speaking, the argumentative strategy deployed in the example is one of saying to an opponent, "You think these things are different, but they aren't."

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a logical fallacy. It is simply wrong.

An argument for a statement is made by applying logic to facts. If a fact is stated with no supporting logic, there is no logical fallacy.